# MySQL CONCAT("string",longtext) results in hex string

Tags: mysql, string, hex, concatenation

I'm experiencing a weird hex string result when trying to concat a string with a column that should be of LONGTEXT type.

The query goes like this:

```
SELECT concat("abc",t.LONGTEXT_VALUE,"cde") FROM mytable t

61626354657374696e67636465
```

The hex string `61626354657374696e67636465` is the correct value, just in hexadecimal form.

A SELECT on the column itself will return the normal string:

```
SELECT t.LONGTEXT_VALUE FROM mytable t

Testing
```

Comment: Are you testing this from the command line mysql client, or with something else?  MySQL May be flagging it as a BLOB in the result set (on the wire) and your client is being "helpful."

Comment: Been trying with both a mysql client as well as a call from some java code. Both are producing the same result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried casting? Usually works pretty well for me. Example:

```
SELECT CONCAT("abc",CAST(t.LONGTEXT_VALUE AS CHAR),"cde") FROM mytable t
```

Comment: Yeah doing a cast works, but I'd rather figure out what's wrong with my function or select in the first place and correct it there.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add a cast to it. ;)

Comment: So is this a bug with the MySQL CONCAT function, i.e. it's not supposed to take longtext values? Should I file it somewhere? Because the function seems to operate on the longtext properly (the hex value is correct), but the hex format it comes out as doesn't match up with the input.

Comment: I see this in the MySQL documentation for concat now: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: > If all arguments are nonbinary strings, the result is a nonbinary string. **If the arguments include any binary strings**, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent binary string form; if you want to avoid that, you can use an explicit type cast...

Answer (score 4):

When you concat a number without a cast it returns as a blob.  This is intended functionality of MySQL as far as I can tell since, it was reported in [this bug thread](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56642) and they closed it and confirmed it was returning a Blob.