# concat string with select count value - mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I want to add string with selected count value from table.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(COUNT(*),' ', if(COUNT(*) > 1, 'rows','row')) AS NoOfRows
FROM myTable;
```

Output :

```
NoOfRows
BLOB
```

Expected :

```
NoOfRows
10 rows
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This query seems to be fine.

Comment: Take a look at this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840557/mysql-concatstring-longtext-results-in-hex-string

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have to use `cast` function.

```
select
    concat(cast(count(*) as char(10)), ' ', if(count(*) > 1, 'rows','row')) as NoOfRows
from myTable;
```

## SQLFiddle DEMO HERE