# CONCAT last number in column in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create a `CONCAT()` that gets the last number in the `exp_id` column, then adds the filename to display as a separate column. The column would display the following.

```
copy \\\resfs\reo\reoexps\87\5\7040445i.pdf C:\temp\images 
CONCAT('copy \\\resfs\reo\reoexps\87\',', SUBSTRING(exp_id, 1,CHAR_LENGTH(exp_id) -1) '\', file_name, 'C:\temp\images') AS D,
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
CONCAT('copy ','\\','\\','\\','resfs\\reo\\reoexps\\87\\', SUBSTRING(CAST(exp_id AS char), 1,CHAR_LENGTH(exp_id) -1),'\\', file_name, ' C:\\temp\\images') AS D
```

Comment: When I try this, The SQL returns  "BLOB"

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18841385/7416478, and try cast to char.

Comment: How am I supposed to CAST to a CHAR and then perform a substring all in the same concat function? Im confused.

Comment: CONCAT('copy ','\\','\\','\\','resfs\\reo\\reoexps\\87\\', CAST(pe.exp_id AS CHAR), SUBSTRING(pe.exp_id, 1,CHAR_LENGTH(pe.exp_id) -1),'\\', pe.file_name, ' C:\\temp\\images') AS D,

Answer (score 0):

The backslash (\) is used as an escape character. Use a double backslash (\\) where you want a literal backslash:

```
CONCAT('copy \\\\resfs\\reo\\reoexps\\87\\', SUBSTRING(exp_id, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(exp_id) -1), '\\', file_name, 'C:\\temp\\images') AS D
```

Comment: For Some reason is says: Error Code: 1583, Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

Comment: select
CONCAT('copy \\\\resfs\\reo\\reoexps\\87\\', SUBSTRING(exp_id, 1,CHAR_LENGTH(exp_id) -1) '\\', file_name, 'C:\\temp\\images') AS D

 from resnet.property_exps as pe